# Finding GCD using divison method in C

Tags: c, function

So I wanted to write a function to calculate the Gcd or HCF of two numbers using the Divison method.This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gcd(int x, int y)
{
    int g,l;
    if (x >= y)
    {
        g = x;
        l = y;
    }

    else
    {
        g = y;
        l = x;
    }
    while (g % l != 0)
    {
        g = l;
        l = g % l;
    }

    printf("The GCD of %d and %d is %d", x, y, l);

}

int main(void)
{
    gcd(8, 3);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting no output with this(error?): `Process returned -1073741676 (0xC0000094)`

Is there a problem with my loop?

Comment: in the else part if the first if, you assign `x = x`. Is that a typo? (`l` does not necessarily have a defined value). In your while loop, you say `g = l` and then you assign `l = g % l`, which is then `l = l % l`. On the next iteration you'll have trouble

Comment: You need three variables too: `g = l; l = g % l;` overwrites the `g` you are about to divide.

Comment: @Ronald fixed it.Still getting error

Comment: `int gcd(int x, int y) { int z; while ((z = x % y) != 0) { x = y; y = z; } return y; }`

Comment: @Weather Vane.Yes that fixed it.

Comment: Code has trouble when the lesser argument is 0 as in `gcd(42, 0)` attempts `42 % 0`. - which is UB.

Comment: Be mindful if accepting negative values for `{x, y}` - the modulus operator `%` might give unexpected results, since C doesn't use the mathematically regular 'Euclidean' definition where the remainder satisfies: `0 <= r < |d|`, for `r = n % d`. Since `gcd(x, y) = gcd(|x|, |y|)`, it might be better for `gcd` to accept `unsigned` parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
        g = l;
        l = g % l;
```

the assignment `g = l` loses the value of `g` before `g % l` is calculated. Change it to:

```
        int t = g % l;
        g = l;
        l = t;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this loop while to find the gcd of two numbers like this:

```
void gcd(int x, int y)
{
    int k=x,l=y;
    if(x>0&&y>0)
    {
        while(x!=0&&y!=0)
        {
           if(x>y)
           {
               x=x-y;
           }
           else
           {
               y=y-x;
           }
        }
    }
  printf("\nThe GCD of %d and %d is %d", k, l, x);
}
int main(void)
{
   gcd(758,306);
   return 0;
}

Examples:

Input:

x=758 , y=306

x=27 , y=45

x=3 , y=8

Output:

printf("\nThe GCD of 758 and 306 is 2");

printf("\nThe GCD of 27 and 45 is 9");

printf("\nThe GCD of 3 and 8 is 1");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, take into account that you are exchanging the numbers when `x >= y` which means that you try to put in `x` the smaller of the two.  For GDC, there's no need to do
this, as the remainder of a division by a bigger number is always the original number, so if you have the sequence `3`, `8`, the first remainder will be `3`, and the numbers switch positions automatically as part of the algorithm.  So there's no need to operate with `g` (I guess for `greater`) and `l` (for `lesser`) so you can avoid that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void gcd(int x, int y)
{
    int g,l;
    if (x >= y)
    {
        g = x;
        l = y;
    }

    else
    {
        g = y;
        l = x;
    }
```

Then, in this second part (the loop part) you have to take into account that you are calculating `g % l` twice in the same loop run (this is not the Euclides' algorithm).

```
    while (g % l != 0)
    {
        g = l;
        l = g % l;
    }
```

You should better use a new variable `r`  (for remainder, but I should recommend you to use longer, descriptive names) so you have always an idea of what the variable holds.

```
    int r;
    while ((r = g % l) != 0) {
        g = l;
        l = r;
    }
```

you see? I just do one division per loop, but you make a `l = g % l;` which modifies the value of l, making you go through **two iterations** of the loop in one.

The final program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int gcd(int greater, int lower)
{
    int remainder;

    while ((remainder = greater % lower) != 0) {
        printf("g=%d, l=%d, r=%d\n", greater, lower, remainder);
        greater = lower;
        lower = remainder;
    }

    return lower; /* remember that remainder got 0 in the last loop */

}

int main(void)
{
    int x = 6, y = 8;

    printf("The GCD of %d and %d is %d\n",
            x, y, gcd(x, y));

    printf("The GCD of %d and %d is %d\n",
            y, x, gcd(y, x));

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

(I have added a trace `printf` in the `gcd()` loop to show how the variables are changing, and both calculations ---changing the parameter values--- to show what I said above about the automatic change in order.  Also, it's better to use the `gcd()` as a function that returns the value, and let `main()` decide if it wants to print results, or use the value for something else.

Enjoy it!! :)